# Using count my tuples are coming out as 1's when a 0 should be present?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count how many times each ID appears in a specific table as follows.

```
Members
ID | NAME
1  | Bob
2  | John
3  | Sally
4  | Hannah

Department
ID | DEPT
 1 |  Math
 1 |  English
 3 |  Math
 4 |  Math
 4 |  English
 4 |  Science
```

I would like to display a table as follows:

```
ID | Name   | Count(Dept)
1  | Bob    |  2
2  | John   |  0
3  | Sally  |  1
4  | Hannah |  3
```

I have made several attempts at this my most recent one being:

```
select owner 
from table
where (select count(distinct letter) from table group by owner) in 
(select max(count(distinct letter)) from table group by owner);
```

I just cannot seem how to get the 0 results to show properly. Honestly, i'm kinda confused as to how to use on ... when you don't want to basically preform a natural join.

edit: I have edited the question to properly show what I am trying to ask. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Don't use `natural join`.  It uses columns that happen to have the same name, rather than declared foreign key constraints.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what should I be using instead. I knew natural join was somewhat dubious but I could not get my query to work otherwise.

Comment: . . Either `ON` or `USING`.

Comment: That is where I run into all my issues. My first assumption was "Well i want to count all entries" so i tried on 1=1 and of course that does exactly what I said which is count all entires, not each entry for each id. honestly, I think a majority of my issues with sql stem from joins and using on. my problem is I cannot simply join on id because that is exactly the same as a natural join isnt it?

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another with suitable sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you really want to do.  This question has no answers, so you could also edit this question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ya. i decided you were right and fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When joining tables it is very important to reference WHICH TABLE each column comes from. To help abbreviate the overall SQL a "table alias" may be defined and used instead of the full table name.

```
select m.id, m.name, count(d.id) as count_d
from members m
left outer join department d on m.id = d.id
group by m.id, m.name
;
```

In the above I have used a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Once you have that outer join defined there may be some rows where no row from `department` is matched to a row in `membesr` and you therefore would get NULLs in all columns related to `department`on that row.

The COUNT() function increments by **1 for every NON-NULL value** it encounters, so what you include inside the parentheses is important. COUNT(*) will increment for every row no matter what. COUNT(d.id) may give zeros because some rows might be NULL in that column.

SEE this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/838d9e/1)**

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/838d9e/1/0)**:

```
| ID |   NAME | COUNT_D |
|----|--------|---------|
|  1 |    Bob |       2 |
|  2 |   John |       0 |
|  3 |  Sally |       1 |
|  4 | Hannah |       3 |
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer a fairly inadequate question. I have edited the question to properly show what i was asking.

Comment: and I have edited my answer, which is largely the same but have removed some guesswork.

Comment: aha! thats it. Thank you!